# Quantity Prediction Algorithm

Tags: predictive-modeling

I want to make prediction for quantity of stock that will be sufficient over a period of time i.e from one delivery to another.

Assuming, i want a store to have minimum amount of item between deliveries e.g 30 items, delivery interval can be 7 , 14, 30, days.

Also i have history data of past delivery interval, amount of item delivered and the amount of item available before next delivery.

What will be the best way to relate these variable: delivery interval and on hand quantity to quantity delivered.

also can i predict quantity to be delivered in other to get a given amount of on hand stock before next delivery.

Comment: This is a function fitting problem. Do you have data to share ? This might suggest which form of functional approximation might be most suitable. If not, why not start with a linear regression and move on from there to add terms in $x^n$.

Comment: @image_doctor thanks, actually that's what i decided to use, Linear Regression, while i observe how that work out.

Comment: Excellent, let us know how it goes, visual inspection of the fit you get can give a good indication of how well your regression model is working.

Comment: Consider [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regressionWikipedia) since you have count data.